# Main background image fixed, and div's background images inside main div fixed as well

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow, parallax

I'm having a problem – actually i want to make something that is like a masked parallax scrolling area.

Maybe a good example is this right here http://davidwalsh.name/parallax
If you scroll down a little there is an iframe with some parallax elements.

I want to have a **main div** with a `background-attachment:fixed;`, and a div inside the **main div** with a fixed background for its section as well, I want to scroll the whole image not only showing parts of the background image while scrolling down

I though it should work by adding `background-attachment:fixed;` to the class `.bg-fix` like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/cuginoCoso/k5zk5m9q/2/

HTML

```
<div id="img-strip">
<div class="bg-fix slide-img"></div>
<div class="bg-fix slide-img"></div>
<div class="bg-fix slide-img"></div>
<div class="bg-fix slide-img"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bg-fix {
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
#img-strip {
    border: 1px solid #ffff00;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
    z-index: 30;
}
.slide-img {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    display: block;
}

.slide-img:nth-child(even) {
    background-image:  url(https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/acid3-100.png);
    background-color: red;
}
.slide-img:nth-child(odd) {
    background-image:  url(http://drublic.de/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/rotate-images.jpg);
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: What exactly is being asked here?  Do you want it to look better when it's scrolled?  Use a `box-shadow` on your clip elements.  Are you looking for advice on how to implement parallax?  Google might be a better option there.  Everything outside the div shouldn't be rendered.  If you want more rendering space, increase the size of the div.  I'm very confused what you're asking for here.

Comment: Im sorry if it is hard to follow. The images in the strip are not being rendered correctly in the area where they are not visible. when you scroll down then the area that was hidden before looks wrong (like there is a problem with the z-sorting or something).
Im looking for a solution where you have a div that you can place anywhere on the page and when you scroll the page you are scrolling the image-strip in the div container. Hope that makes it a little bit more clear

Answer (score 1):

I understood what you were asking for after a while :P Here's the solotion for it: http://jsfiddle.net/k5zk5m9q/5/

```
/* Remove this line below from your CSS */
.bg-fix {background-attachment: fixed;}

/* Add background-attachment: fixed; to .slide-img:nth-child(odd) */
.slide-img:nth-child(odd) {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image:  url(http://drublic.de/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/rotate-images.jpg);
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you but i think this is still not what i'm looking for. This shoud make it perfectly clear. This scrolls and does not render the area which is not shown, when not scrolled.
http://jsfiddle.net/cuginoCoso/k5zk5m9q/6/
If i take the    overflow:scroll    out, the images behave right, but they are not masked by the div anymore.
http://jsfiddle.net/cuginoCoso/k5zk5m9q/7/

Comment: what you're are trying to say is that the div only scrolls if you hover it?! and if you scroll outside the div it doesn't scroll, is that your problem?

Comment: You're asking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/k5zk5m9q/8/ or actually make the `#img-strip` as your background? You can only scroll the div with the images only if you hover it, if you're trying to scroll outside the div then you are trying to scroll the `<body>` but you can make it if you fill the intire page like I did on this Jsfiddle link example

Comment: i think i came up with something that it very close by using the background-size attribute. http://jsfiddle.net/cuginoCoso/k5zk5m9q/9/
The only problem now is that when you scroll the top margin scrolls away. I want this div to be kinda fixed but still scrollabel.

Comment: and this would be a quick and dirty solution. Mask it with another div which is covering the area. But i wish there would be a much more elegant way to do this.
http://jsfiddle.net/cuginoCoso/k5zk5m9q/10/